# Locally Flat Understanding

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I wanted to make sure that I was definitely understanding the proof of locally flat correctly.  I can't see to find a similar proof to the one in the book, so I'm not super sure if my understanding/interpretation is correct.  The book that I'm using is "Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell" by Anthony Zee.

Starting with the coordinate transform for a metric,
$$g'_{\lambda\sigma}(x')=g_{\mu\nu}(x)\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\lambda}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x'^\sigma}$$
if we expand the metric in unprimed coordinates up to the second order
$$g_{\mu\nu}\approx g_{\mu\nu}(0)+A_{\mu\nu,\lambda}x^\lambda+B_{\mu\nu,\lambda\sigma}x^\lambda x^\sigma + ...$$
where we have centered the metric on $x=0$.

We can likewise expand the coordinate transformation as
$$x^\mu\approx K^\mu_\lambda x'^\lambda+L^\mu_{\lambda\nu}x'^\lambda x'^\nu+M^\mu_{\lambda\nu\sigma}x'^\lambda x'^\nu x'^\sigma+...$$
If we take the partial derivative,
$$\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\lambda}\approx K^\mu_\lambda+L^\mu_{\lambda\nu}x'^\nu+M^\mu_{\lambda\nu\sigma} x'^\nu x'^\sigma+...$$
Since we are looking for the local result, we drop all other terms s.t.
$$\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x'^\lambda}\approx K^\mu_\lambda$$
so at a local level the metric transform is
$$g'_{\lambda\sigma}(x')\approx g_{\mu\nu}(0)K^\mu_\lambda K^\nu_\sigma$$
Since $K^\mu_\lambda$ is summing over the row index, in matrix representation we can express this as
$$g'\approx K^TgK$$
since the metric is by definition real and symmetric, g can always be diagonalised.

Is anything in the above wrong?  The power series is from the book, and I think it kind of makes sense?  Something about it feels a bit off, but I can't quite put my finger on what, so I'd love some confirmation on whether I've understood the proof correctly.  Thanks!

Comment: what does "locally flat" mean? curvature is given by rieman curvature tensor and flatness is equivalent to this tensor vanishing. Tensor is local quantity by definition and if it is nonvanishing in one coordinate frame, it is nonvanishing in every coordinate frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost correct, save for two things.

One is more about pedantry, but I *really, really* dislike when people say "expand" or "drop", it makes it sound like this is some nebulous infinitesimal-y, approximation-y thing. It isn't.

Let's say we want to construct a "locally flat" (which is itself a kinda bad term, let's use "Riemann normal coordinates" instead) coordinate system at $x_0$.

As a first step, we can make a translational coordinate transformation such that $x_0^i=0$ (I am gonna use latin indices in this answer).

Now, we are going to perform a coordinate transformation where we do not "expand" anything, we simply want to make the coordinate transformation a linear homogenous polynomial, so we write $$ x^i=A^i_{\ j}x^{\prime j}, $$ then $$ \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\prime j}}=A^i_{\ j}. $$

A thing to note is that adding higher order terms to the coordinate transformation won't change a thing, since if $$ x^i=A^i_{\ j}x^{\prime j}+B^i_{\ jk}x^{\prime j}x^{\prime k}, $$ then $$ \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\prime j}}=A^i_{\ j}+B^i_{\ jk}x^{\prime k}, $$ but the point $x_0$ has coordinates $0$, so if we evaluate the derivative at $x^i=0$ we get $$ \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\prime j}}(0)=A^i_{\ j}. $$ We did not have to "drop" anything at all.

The transformation of the metric components at $0$ is $$ g^\prime_{ij}(0)=\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial x^{\prime i}}(0)\frac{\partial x^l}{\partial x^{\prime j}}(0)g_{kl}(0)=A^k_{\ i}A^l_{\ j}g_{kl}(0), $$ so we may choose the coefficients $A^i_{\ j}$ such that $g^\prime_{ij}=\eta_{ij}$, since now we are working at a single point and all things here are constant matrices.

However what makes a coordinate system a Riemannian normal system (or a "locally flat" system if one'd like) about $x_0$ is not that the metric is Minkowskian at the point $x_0$, but that in addition to that, the Christoffel symbol vanishes at that point. The transformation of the Christoffel symbol is $$ \Gamma^{\prime n}_{\ lm}=\Gamma^k_{\ ij}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\prime l}}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^{\prime m}}\frac{\partial x^{\prime n}}{\partial x^k}+\frac{\partial x^{\prime n}}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial^2 x^i}{\partial x^{\prime l}\partial x^{\prime m}}, $$ if the LHS is zero, then this simplifies to $$ -\frac{\partial^2 x^k}{\partial x^{\prime l}\partial x^{\prime m}}=\Gamma^k_{\ ij}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^{\prime l}}\frac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^{\prime m}}, $$ and if we evaluate at $0$ and insert the above-written *quadratic* transformation, we get $$ -B^k_{\ lm}=\Gamma^k_{\ ij}(0)A^i_{\ l}A^j_{\ m}, $$ thus if $A^i_{\ j}$ is any matrix that transforms the metric at $0$ into Minkowskian form, then the coordinate transformation $$ x^i=A^i_{\ j}x^{\prime j}-\Gamma^i_{\ jk}(0)A^j_{\ l}A^k_{\ m}x^{\prime l}x^{\prime m} $$ has the effect that at $x_0=0$ we have $$ g_{ij}(0)=\eta_{ij} \\ \Gamma^i_{\ jk}(0)=0 \\ (\partial_i g_{jk})(0)=0. $$

Comment: Hi thanks this helps a lot, but is there a way to explain this without the Christoffel symbol?  It's just that my book hasn't actually introduced them yet (which has made finding sources very difficult).  This has been super helpful though, thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Redcrazyguy If you just want the canonical form of the metric, then sure, but the whole point of the "local flatness" business is not just that the metric is in canonical form at the point, but that the metric's first derivatives also vanish at that point. And you kinda have to involve Christoffel symbols then.